# oracle mybatis generator java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Tags: java, oracle, mybatis-generator

I'm trying to establish a SSM project with oracle in IDEA. I'm new to oracle and I have problems using MyBatis generator to generate tables from oracle.

I can use SQL to get data from my database but when I try to generate it I got errors `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`

Here's my errors:

[image]

Here's my code

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE generatorConfiguration
        PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD MyBatis Generator Configuration 1.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-generator-config_1_0.dtd">

<generatorConfiguration>

    <properties resource="jdbc.properties"></properties>

    <context id="testTables" targetRuntime="MyBatis3">
        <commentGenerator>

            <property name="suppressAllComments" value="true" />
        </commentGenerator>

        <jdbcConnection driverClass="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
                        connectionURL="${jdbc.url}"
                        userId="${jdbc.username}"
                        password="${jdbc.password}">
        </jdbcConnection>

 
        <javaTypeResolver>
            <property name="forceBigDecimals" value="false" />
        </javaTypeResolver>


        <javaModelGenerator targetPackage="com.yulan.pojo"
                            targetProject=".\src">

            <property name="enableSubPackages" value="false" />
     
            <property name="trimStrings" value="true" />
        </javaModelGenerator>

        <sqlMapGenerator targetPackage="mappers"
                         targetProject=".\resource">
            <property name="enableSubPackages" value="false" />
        </sqlMapGenerator>
  
        <javaClientGenerator type="XMLMAPPER"
                             targetPackage="com.yulan.dao"
                             targetProject=".\src">
            <property name="enableSubPackages" value="false" />
        </javaClientGenerator>

        <table tableName="CUSTOMER" domainObjectName="Customer"></table>
    </context>
</generatorConfiguration>
```

Here's my pom.xml:

[image]

and here's my maven denpendency:

[image]

Can anyone tell me why? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make the Oracle driver a dependency of the generator, not your project in general. You can see an example of that here: https://github.com/mybatis/generator/blob/master/core/mybatis-generator-systests-mybatis3-java8/pom.xml#L48-L79